# Angular: Reactive Forms

Tags: angular, ionic3

Hello I am following a tutorial from these links:
http://plnkr.co/edit/nHSIsciSZNTQzQjxkXsk?p=preview
http://plnkr.co/edit/hQ6RtzCfPosfQl4HlbZQ?p=preview

and getting an error as follows:

```
Cannot find control with path: 'fields -> personName
```

Here is the HTML im currently working on I'm not sure what is causing the error since I'm just following the tutorial

```
<form [formGroup]="createDirectoryForm" novalidate (ngSubmit)="save()">
    <div class="spacer-30"></div>
    <div class="form-group1">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" formControlName="directoryName" placeholder="Directory Name" />
    </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="spacer-20"></div>
    <div class="form-group2" formArrayName="fields">
    <div *ngFor="let field of createDirectoryForm.controls.fields.controls; let i=index" class="panel">
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" formControlName="number" placeholder="Number" />
    </div> 
    <div class="spacer-10"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" formControlName="personName" placeholder="Name" />
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" formControlName="age" placeholder="Age" />
    </div>
    <div class="spacer-10"></div>
    <div class="row">
      <input type="text" formControlName="address" placeholder="Address" />
    </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="margin-20">
          <div>myForm details:-</div>
          <pre>Is myForm valid?: <br>{{myForm.valid | json}}</pre>
          <pre>form value: <br>{{myForm.value | json}}</pre>
        </div>
    </form>
```

and the ts.file for the component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams, ViewController } from 'ionic-angular';
import { FormGroup, FormArray, FormBuilder, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import{Directory} from './directoryInfo.interface'

/**
 * Generated class for the ModalCreateNewDirectoryPage page.
 *
 * See http://ionicframework.com/docs/components/#navigation for more info
 * on Ionic pages and navigation.
 */


@Component({
  selector: 'page-modal-create-new-directory',
  templateUrl: 'modal-create-new-directory.html',
})
export class ModalCreateNewDirectoryPage implements OnInit  {

  createDirectoryForm: FormGroup;
  //directoryInfo: {directoryName: string, number: string, personName: string, age: string, address: string,} = {directoryName:'',number: '', personName: '', age: '', address:''};

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams, public newDirectoryView:ViewController, private formBuilder: FormBuilder) {

  }

  ngOnInit(){
        this.createDirectoryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
            directoryName:['',Validators.required],
            fields: this.formBuilder.array([
                [''],
            ])

        });
    }

  /*ngOnInit(){
      this.createDirectoryForm = this.formBuilder.group({
          directoryName:[''],
          number:['',Validators.required],
          personName: [''],
          age:[''],
          address:[''],
      });
  }*/

  initFormChild() {
        return this.formBuilder.group({
            number:['',Validators.required],
            personName: [''],
            age:[''],
            address:[''],
        });
    }

  addFormChild() {
        const control = <FormArray>this.createDirectoryForm.controls['fields'];
        control.push(this.formBuilder.control(['']));
    }

  save(form){
    console.log('asdas');
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad ModalCreateNewDirectoryPage');
  }

  closeNewDirectoryModal(){
    this.newDirectoryView.dismiss();
  }



}
```

as well as the interface needed i modified a bit but still based on the guide

```
export interface Directory {
    directoryName: string;
    fields: Field[];
}

export interface Field {
    number: string;
    personName: string;
    age: string;
    address:string;
}
```

I actually seen some people resolved this issue but It's not quite clear how they did it. Any suggestion is greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: can you replicate a plunker for this issue, and you can also check this link for Angular and Forms  https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts

Comment: @Rahul Singh im trying to build the plunker now

Comment: I think I figured it out apparently it has something to do with how i wrote my html it has to be in a proper format or else it won't get read at all

Comment: You can check that oibk for further queries on forms

Comment: You should post your findings and accept your own answer... question will not show up as unanswered then..

Answer (score 1):

Turns out that what I was doing is correct, It's just that my html is not properly formatted and that is what was causing the error for Form Builder.